# Drawing a Bezier Curve using Firemonkey

Tags: firemonkey

How do I draw a Bezier curve using Firemonkey (XE6)? The documentation is currently a little sparse in the XE6 wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code can be used to draw a simple Bezier curve using Firemonkey XE6. Create a new Firemonkey application, and in the Form OnPaint handler include the code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRectF);
var path : TPathData;
begin
  path := TPathData.Create;
  try
    path.MoveTo(TPointF.Create (10,100));
    path.CurveTo (TPointF.Create(100,10),TPointF.Create(150,150),
                  TPointF.Create(200,100));
    Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 2;
    Canvas.Stroke.Color := claRed;
    Canvas.BeginScene;
    Canvas.DrawPath(path, 1.0);
    Canvas.EndScene;
  finally
    path.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The CurveTo takes three arguments, the two Bezier control points and the final point. MoveTo provides the starting point.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed code for new versions:

```
procedure TForm2.FormPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRectF);
var path : TPathData;
begin
  path := TPathData.Create;
  try
    path.MoveTo(TPointF.Create (10,100));
    path.CurveTo (TPointF.Create(100,10),TPointF.Create(150,150),
                  TPointF.Create(200,100));
    Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 2;
    Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
    Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Red;
    Canvas.BeginScene;
    Canvas.DrawPath(path, 1.0);
    Canvas.EndScene;
  finally
    path.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you need to draw simplest 3 points curve:

```
path.MoveTo(Point1);
CurveTo (Point2, Point2, Point3);
```

Btw this code does not draw lines directly through XY, because of specifics of Bezier algorithm, if you need exact graph -  ask me (or you can search for javascript code, it's easy to translate it to delphi.).